# How to disable root account on MacBook Pro if I don't know root password

Tags: directory, root, macos, non-root-user

I bought a used MacBook Pro 2017 from a reseller but I found restrictions in accessing many places. Then I realized this machine is already configured with a root user which I don't even know. How would you be safe inside a machine which an unknown person has access to everything ?? Please help me with this.

Comment: macOS is a bit special and it's unclear whether you mean that you can't access the root user account (with eg sudo) or whether you need to write to the parts of the system that ordinarily not even root can write to.  It's also unclear how you have determined that somebody else has access to your system.

Comment: I mean there is arleady a root user set inside the MacBook. Like an MDM service used by an organization. It won't be listed inside anywhere inside the list. You got me ?

Comment: No sorry I don't. A macOS system always has a root user. This is not strange.